# How to click more than one image using camera plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I want to click three image one by one on button click using camera plugin. My first image click work fine but, I get second and third image path null.
How can I click three image on loop using camera plugin.
I use https://pub.dev/packages/camera plugin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using this package for this type of feature https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_wechat_assets_picker

Comment: I want to click image from my app. For that I want to put camera preview in my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin [images_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/images_picker).

You can declare how many pictures you want to select and other parameters.